# Issue with pandas printing CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
spy = pd.read_csv("spydatacsv.csv", header=0)
print(spy.head())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christianwooldridge/PycharmProjects/1/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/christianwooldridge/PycharmProjects/1/pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    spy = pd.read_csv("spydatacsv.csv", header=0)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: The problem is not in printing the file, it's in the `read_csv()` call. It looks like you may have named your script `pandas.py`. If so, rename it something else.

Comment: @martineau good catch

Comment: @adhg: Seen it before and know the telltale signs.…